# Insert values generated by PHP in a Javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to make a list where the user can select 5 items. Those items are generated through PHP. When the user clicks on 1 item that item needs to be saved in an Javascript array. Once the user selected 5 items, those needs to be saved into an mysql database.

Atm I can select items, but the array remains empty.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var genrearray = new Array(4);
        var i=1; 

        $(document).ready(function kleurveranderen() {
            $(".keuzeDiv").on("click", function kleurveranderen() {
                if(i<=5){   
                        $(this).toggleClass("green");
                        genrearray[i] = document.getElementById("$Keuzescherm['Genrenaam']").innerHTML;
                        i++;

            }
        else{
                alert("Teveel genres geselecteerd.");
            }

        })
        });</script>
```

this is standing between script tags but for some reason he isnt showing them.

my php code:

```
<?php while($Keuzescherm= $allGenres->fetch_assoc())
{
       echo "<div class='keuzeDiv' id='".$Keuzescherm['Genrenaam'] ."'>" 
              . $Keuzescherm['Genrenaam']."</div>"; 
    }?>
```

the id of the div is the same as the value.

my css code to indicate that the div is selected

```
.keuzeDiv{
background-color:#dddddd; 
padding-top:5%;
color: black;
padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
.green{
    background-color:#8eb461; 
    color:white;}
```

So my question is: **How can I fill the array with the php values and save that array to a MySql database?**

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should be doing is:

```
genrearray[i] = $(this).text();
```

You can't reference PHP variables in Javascript. And the variable you were trying to reference is from the `while` loop, so its value outside the loop is not very useful.